# Low hanging letters are cut off when label is in grid

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin.forms

With the following XAML, the bottoms of g and p characters are being cut off for the labels.
If I take them out of the grid, it all works perfect

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" CornerRadius="20" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
        <Label Text="RSR" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="40" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName,FallbackValue='Display Name ggpp'}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding SecondLine,FallbackValue='Second Line ggpp'}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding ThirdLine,FallbackValue='Third Line ggpp'}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="12"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image: example image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi , I have tried shared code in my local site , it shows no problem . I want to know you put `Grid` inside which `Father Layout` .  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D3cK.png

Comment: Its the first element within a stacklayout, which itself is the only child of the ContentPage.Content element

Comment: Okey , that's the same with mine . You can see that my shared screenshot with no problem . You can share the full code of `Xaml` or a sample project link here , I will check that .

Answer (score 0):

Try set `Grid RowSpacing` to 0, it has default value of 6

Comment: if anything, this made it worse